# Short-term insurance Ontario, Canada (buying car before moving out of province)

Tags: canada, automobiles, insurance, ontario

I’m currently living in Toronto, ON but I’m planning to move to central BC in a few weeks. I’m planning on buying a new car and driving it from Ontario to BC and making a trip out of it. However, I will need to get insurance in Ontario to cover me during the drive but then switch to BC insurance once I get there.

Does anyone know of any insurance companies that provide short-term car insurance or have low or no cancellation fees in Ontario?

Comment: In UK when you buy a car from a dealer, they can sometimes give you one week's complimentary insurance to tide you over.

Comment: It’s different here. You have to have insurance before you can pick up your car from the dealer. Thanks though